# std::string manipulating error on C++Builder 6

Tags: c++, string, frame, c++builder, c++builder-6

I am creating a class for a project using an Emericc axe. The goal of this class is to use the error frames to return a message. I have to use only STL's std::string variables.
However, the IDE doesn't recognize any string manipulation after one of the find functions.

Note that I'm French, so the variables I use are in my language (the code is pretty simple tho).

The error I encounter is in this function:

```
string ErrMericc::ErrTrame(string trame)
{
  /*
   trame(fr) = frame(eng)
   virgule(fr) = comma(eng) [I shortened "virgule" to "virg" in a variable]
  */

  this->trame=trame;
  trame.find('!', posExcl); //this marks the beginnig of the error number

  if(posExcl == string::npos)
  {
    trame.clear(); //clearing in case the variable is not empty
    //in case this is not an error frame
    trame.push_back("Erreur 200 : "+errors[200]+". La trame envoyée n'est pas une trame d'erreur."); 
    return trame; 
  }
  else
  {
    trame.find(',', posVirg); //here is the error
    //starting here, no function using a string is recognized by the IDE
    //and I don't find why
    nb.push_back(trame.substr(posExcl+2, posVirg)); //unrecognized push_back() and substr()

    errNb=StrToInt(trame.c_str());
    trame=errors[errNb];
    return "Erreur "+IntToStr(errNb)+" : "+trame;
  }

}
```

C++Builder 6 tells me : [C++ Error] ErrMericc.cpp(1): impossible to call code execution, because of source code errors.
When I double click on this error message, it brings me at the first line of source code in the file.

The error message doesn't seem to stop popping except if I comment out the "trame.find(',', posVirg);".

Could you please explain me where my error is?

**EDIT:**

It looks like C++ Builder 6 just doesn't like the code line...

This works:

```
    trame.find(',', posVirg); //here is the error
    //starting here, no function using a string is recognized by the IDE
    //and I don't find why
    nb.push_back(trame.substr(posExcl+2, posVirg)); //unrecognized push_back() and substr()
```

This doesn't:

```
    //here is the error
    //starting here, no function using a string is recognized by the IDE
    //and I don't find why
    trame.find(',', posVirg); 
    nb.push_back(trame.substr(posExcl+2, posVirg)); //unrecognized push_back() and substr()
```

Weird.

I'm starting to think the problem comes from the IDE. 
So far, I've tried copying and moving the files into a new folder, but the malfunction isn't affected.

Comment: Do you have a more precise error message ? I'm afraid the current information is too vague to diagnose the problem. Please also note that C++ Builder 6 was released in 2002, which makes it a very old and outdated compiler.

Comment: @SirDarius Unfortunately I don't... Here is a [screencap](http://s28.postimg.org/7bz1gntfx/stack_Overflow_builder_String_err_Window.png), maybe it can help.  
This is a school project, so I'm required to use that version (although I'd enjoy something more recent).

Comment: This is the same error that you quoted in your question. What are the "errors in the source code" ? This is pretty surprising. As far as I remember, C++ Builder was always helpful to me with its error messages when I used it back then.

Comment: I found the error with some IRL help, and documentation about the std::strings.  
@SirDarius Thanks for your time and help :)

Comment: On a side note, you are misusing `std::string::find()`. The second parameter is an **input** parameter (the starting position of the search) but you are treating it as if it were an **output** parameter (the result of the search). Change `trame.find('!', posExcl)` to `posExcl = trame.find('!')`, `trame.find(',', posVirg)` to `posVirg = trame.find(',', posExcl+2)`, and `nb.push_back(trame.substr(posExcl+2, posVirg))` to `nb = trame.substr(posExcl+2, posVirg-(posExcl+2))`. Also, `StrToInt(trame.c_str())` will always fail due to the punctuation, you likely wanted `StrToInt(nb.c_str())` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the error came from my using of the push_back() function : I can push back only one char at a time.
Inputing multiple values in one memory location, made to contain one char, wasn't a good idea.

Apparently, C++Builder 6 just didn't know what to do as the errors came from my use of something in the stl.

So I shouldn't have done :

```
trame.push_back("Erreur 200 : "+errors[200]+". La trame envoyée n'est pas une trame d'erreur.");
```

But :

```
trame = string("Erreur 200 : ") + errors[200] + string(". La trame envoyée n'est pas une trame d'erreur.");
```

Comment: `std::string` is a container of `char` values, so `push_back()` only accepts  `char` values. Just like a `std::vector<T>` can `push_back()` only `T` values. In every container type,  `push_back()` only accepts values of the container's element type.

Comment: In this case, if I *really* wanted to use a function, I should have use std::string::append().  Thanks for your helpful comments.